# Live streaming from webcam in a browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, html5-video, wowza

I am working on a live-streaming prototype, I have been reading a lot about how live-streaming works and many different approaches but I still can't find a live-streaming stack that suits my needs...

These are the requirements for my prototype:

1)The video/audio recording must come from a web browser using the webcam, the idea is that the client preferably shouldn't need to install plugins or do anything complicated(maybe installing Flash player plugin is acceptable, only for recording the video, the viewers should be able to view the stream without plugins).

2)It can't be peer to peer since I also need to store the entire video in my server (or in Amazon s3 servers for example) for viewing later.

3)The viewers should also be able to watch the stream without the need of installing anything, from their web browsers, say Chrome and Firefox for example. We want to use the HTML5 video tag if possible.

4)The prototype should be constructed without expending money preferably. I have seen that AWS-Cloudfront and Wowza offer free trials so we are thinking about using these 2 services.

5)The prototype should be able to maintain 1 live stream at a time and 2 viewers, just that, so there are no restrictions regarding this.

**Any suggestions?**

I am specially stuck/confused with the uploading/encoding video part of the architecture(I am new to streaming and all the formats/codecs/protocols/technologies are making it really hard to digest).

As of right now, I came across WebRTC that apparently allows me to do what I want, record and encode video from the browser using the webcam, but this API only works with HTTPS sites. **Are there any alternatives that work with HTTP sites?**

The other part that I am not completely sure about is the need for an encoding server, for example Wowza Streaming Engine, why do I need it? Isn't it enough if I use for example WebRTC for encoding the video and then I just send it to the distribution service (AWS-Cloudfront for example)? I do understand that the encoding server would allow me to support many different devices since it will create lots of different encodings and serve many different HTTP protocols, but do I need it for this prototype? I just want to make a 1 format (MP4 for example) live-stream that can be viewed in 2 web browsers, that's all, I don't need variety of formats nor support for different bandwidths or devices.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your requirement, WebRTC is good way.

> API only works with HTTPS sites. Are there any alternatives that work
>   with HTTP sites?

No. Currently Firefox is only browser is allow WebRTC on HTTP, but finally it need HTTPS

Answer (score -1):

For doing this prototype you need to go with the Wowza WebRTC.

While going with wowza all the streams are delivered from the wowza only.So it become a routed WebRTC.

Install Wowza - https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-wowza-streaming-engine

Enable the WebRTC - https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-webrtc-with-wowza-streaming-engine

Downaload and configure the Streamlock. or Selfsigned JKS file - https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-request-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-certificate-authority

Download the sample WebRTC - https://www.wowza.com/_private/webrtc/

Publish stream using the Publish HTML and Play through the Play HTML ( Supported Chrome,Firefox & Opera Browsers)

For MP4 files in WebRTC : you need to enable the transcoder with h264 & aac. Also you need to enable the option Record all the incoming Streams in the properties of application which you are creating for the WebRTC ( Not the DVR ).Using the File writer module save all the recorded files in a custom location.By using a custom script(Bash,Python) Move all the Transcoded files to the s3 bucket, Deliver through cloudfront.